# Sum of the first $n$ terms of a geometric progression: two different forms

Tags: calculus

I've found two different ways of writing a sum of the first $n$ terms of a geometric progression.

One is: $$S_{n}=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$

The other is:$$S_{n}=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

I saw that the first is related with sequences and the second is related to series (sigma notation). But I didn't understand the difference between both. Can you give me some clues? Thanks.

---

EDIT

I've found the second in this example:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}r^n=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

Comment: Found where? The second is $1+r+\dots + r^n$, which has $r+1$ terms, but ends with $r^n$ so you might confuse it with having $n$ terms.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I've just edit the question

Comment: That second example is not $n$ terms, it is $n+1$ terms. For instance, when $n=1$, $1+r$ is the sum of two terms of the geometric progression.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews but the up boundary of the sigma notation is $n$. I'don't understand!! $n$ can be equal zero, and therefore the first term is $1$($r^0$)

Comment: You're correct, the first term is $r^0$, and in general, the $j$th term is $r^{j-1}$. Thus, $r^n$ is the $(n+1)$st term, and so **isn't** one of the first $n$ terms.

Comment: How many terms does $x_0+x_1+x_2$ have? Just because the "up" term is $n$ doesn't mean that the number of terms is $n$. The up term does not count the number of terms, it names the last term.

Comment: Now I understand. if I wanted that the first term matched $k=1$ I'd have to write $r^{k-1}$ because the first term is $r^0=1$. Thank you both for the help

Comment: Here is a way to remember it to avoid confusion for the sum of a geometric series: find First term F, ratio R=second/first, the next `after` last term N, then the sum is (F-N)/(1-R)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all down to how you define $S_n$. Consider the general form of the series:

$$1+r+r^2+r^3+\cdots+r^k$$

If you define $S_n$ to be the sum of the first $n$ terms then you have:

$$S_n = 1 + r + r^2 + \cdots + r^{n-1}=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$

because the $1$ is the first term, $r$ is the second, $r^2$ is the third, ..., and $r^{n-1}$ is the $n^{th}$ term.

If define $S_n$ to be the sum, up to and including, the $n^{th}$-order term (the $r^n$ term) then

$$S_n = 1+ r + r^2 + \cdots + r^n = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

The accepted way, which applies to all series and partial sums, is to use $S_n$ to mean the sum of the first $n$ terms. In that case, the first formula is "correct".

Answer (score 7):

Well, the difference is this: the first is correct, and the second isn't. The first sums terms from $r^0=1$ through $r^{n-1}$--the first $n$ terms. The second sums $r^0=1$ through $r^n$--the first $n+1$ terms.